# Pattern matching cp -r

Tags: linux, command-line

Why does `cp -r .*/ _dotfiles/` copy all files and directories and not just hidden directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The glob pattern `.*` matches the current directory (`.`) and the parent directory (`..`).

Try this:

```
cp -r .[^.]*/ _dotfiles
```